# Slow CREATE TABLE with MariaDB engine ColumnStore

Tags: mysql, mariadb, innodb, columnstore

1. System: Ubuntu 18 - SSD
2. MariaDB ColumnStore version: 1.2.5
3. Table rows: 3

If you compare the create table operation between the one made by InnoDB in front of ColumnStore, InnoDB run X times faster than ColumnStore.

I have perform some CREATE TABLE with INSERT AS SELECT using engine ColumnStore. The results Is very slow. This is the sequence:

```sql
DROP table IF EXISTS example;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS example
  (num INT(11),meta DECIMAL(14,4),min INT(11),max INT(11))
ENGINE=columnstore;

INSERT INTO example 
 (num, meta, min, max)
AS SELECT num, meta, min, max FROM old_example;

-- TIME TO EXECUTE
-- On row affected, taking 2.8s
```

Now, take a looke at how I have done with InnoDB

```sql
DROP table IF EXISTS example;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS example
  (num INT(11),meta DECIMAL(14,4),min INT(11),max INT(11))
  (SELECT num, meta, min, max FROM old_example);

-- TIME TO EXECUTE
-- On row affected, taking 103ms
```

**Take note 1**: I do know that on the first I do one more operation and it is different, but I did a trace doing each one of the queries separated, and I found out that the CREATE TABLE with ENGINE=ColumnStore is the one that takes so long.
**Take note 2**: MariaDB columnstore has now [CREATE AS SELECT operation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/columnstore-create-table/).

Given that, here is some questions:

**Question 1**: Is there some MariaDB ColumnStore configuration that I can do to make possible creating table operation then insert data from another table be faster?
**Question 2**: Is MariaDB ColumnStore faster just for selecting?

Comment: Why does this matter? You create a table once, not frequently.

Comment: It doesn't sound like this is a problem with your code, so I don't know what you expect us to help you with. See https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-columnstore/ for links to the ColumnStore forum and MariaDB's Jira system for reporting bugs.

Comment: first the maria serve grabs the code then the columnstore engine and then still another all optimize. nut the most timeconsoming is to get faster select and joins you need some overhead during creation/insert also see https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-columnstore-performance-concepts/

Comment: @Barmar It matter on my application. It is a workflow to transform data and show its results in a dashboard. Sometimes one workflow goes back on `create table` many times

Answer (score 0):

The speed difference is to be expected.

Based on the timings, I suspect the dataset is tiny.

Columnstore is designed to handle very large datasets, thereby not being optimized for tiny sets.

Looking at the internal structure of a Columnstore, you will find some large structures, compression, and indexing of every column.  Also, there are many compression techniques possible; it probably studies the data carefully to decide which one to use for each column.  All of these are aimed at the performance of SELECTs, at the expense of any other operations.

Your InnoDB table has no indexes, no compression, and the disk footprint, in spite of no compression, is probably much less.  (With a larger table, InnoDB would be bigger.)

Columnstore has a niche; use it for that; don't expect it to be competitive to InnoDB in all areas.